# How to Import Font family in Magento?

Tags: javascript, html, magento

I am preparing mangento homepage and i want to change the font-family as

> opensans

but that font family not available in magento. how to import that opensans.

help me out here,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first to insert the font files:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And in the css you can use then;

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```